# Programmatically close Custom Chrome Tabs in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, chrome-custom-tabs

In my use case, I have an Activity that opens CustomChromeTab. After some actions, deep links back to my app.

Instead, Is there any way I can close the CustomChromeTab programmatically?